# UITableView compiling error in AppDelegate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

This is my **Viewcontroller:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let list = ["Facebook: 2000$", "Twitter: 10000$", "Vine: 23356$", "Uber: 35000", "Adobe Systems: 400900", "Agilent Tech: 456700", "Ebay: 98899"]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return (list.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return(cell)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**and my app delegate:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) { etc..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: please explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: my problem is that when i try to run it, 4 lines down in appdelegate there is a compiling error.

Comment: And what does that compiling error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It may be missing-**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourTableView.delegate = self
    yourTableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: Not giving `delegate` & `datasource` to `self` never gives the error, but your `delegates` methods never calls